# Video as background, how to put it on loop?

Tags: jquery, html, loops, html5-video

I am using georgepaterson / jquery-videobackground on this page:

http://kimcolemanprojects.com/index.html

I want the video to loop but have no idea how to do this within JQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('dl').toggle();
            $('h2').bind('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('dl').slideToggle(500, function() {
                    $('.video-background').videobackground('resize');
                });
            });
            $('body').prepend('<div class="video-background"></div>');
            $('.video-background').videobackground({
                videoSource: [['video/ribbons_450x360.mp4', 'video/mp4'],
                    ['video/ribbons_450x360.webmhd.webm', 'video/webm'], 
                    ['video/ribbons_450x360.oggtheora.ogv', 'video/ogg']], 
                controlPosition: '#main',
                poster: 'video/ribbs.png',
                loadedCallback: function() {
                    $(this).videobackground('mute');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's not an answer, but I'd vote strongly for not putting video as a background at all, it's just horrible / bad practice and hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a html5 video, set it's loop attribute to "loop" like this:

```
loop="loop"
```

or just loop without a value like this:

```
loop
```

If you need to do that strictly with jQuery do this:

```
$('video').attr('loop','loop');
```

Also, check out [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html) to learn everything you need to know about html5 video elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the script above, where do I put loop within it?

Comment: Just add the loop attribute anywhere, so it looks like this:
` <video preload="none" poster="video/ribbs.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"> `

Also, make sure you accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks. I had to change bottom part of Jquery script loop: true, as there is no video tag in my html - its all in the javascript. Thanks for your help.